# RecyclerView Adapter error after deleting item from ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, indexoutofboundsexception

I have 2 `RecyclerView` Adapter named `AddDrinkAdapter` and `DrinkDetailAdapter`.

`AddDrinkAdapter` is to list different types of drinks and the desired quantity.

While `DrinkDetailAdapter` is to list those drinks with its detail.

This is my `AddDrinkAdapter` Class

```
public class AddDrinkAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AddDrinkViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<DrinkQuantity> listDrinkQuantity = new ArrayList<>();
private AddDrinkFragment.callbackListener listener;
private final int min = 0;
private final int max = 5;

AddDrinkAdapter(ArrayList<DrinkQuantity> listDrinkQuantity, AddDrinkFragment.callbackListener callbackListener) {
    this.listDrinkQuantity = listDrinkQuantity;
    listener = callbackListener;
}

public ArrayList<DrinkQuantity> getListDrinkQuantity() {
    return listDrinkQuantity;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public AddDrinkViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_drink_quantity, parent, false);

    return new AddDrinkViewHolder(itemView);
}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AddDrinkViewHolder holder, int position) {
    DrinkQuantity drinkQuantity = listDrinkQuantity.get(position);
    holder.mTvName.setText(drinkQuantity.getDrinkType());
    holder.mEtQuantity.setText(Integer.toString(drinkQuantity.getQuantity()));

    holder.mEtQuantity.addTextChangedListener(setTextWatcher(position, holder.mEtQuantity));
    holder.mIvMinus.setOnClickListener(onClick(holder, position, "minus"));
    holder.mIvAdd.setOnClickListener(onClick(holder, position, "add"));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listDrinkQuantity.size();
}

private TextWatcher setTextWatcher(int position, EditText et){
    return new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            String value = charSequence.toString();
            if(!Util.isNullOrEmpty(value.trim())) {
                int num = Integer.parseInt(charSequence.toString());
                if(num < 0 || num > 5) {
                    listener.onChangeText(min, max, num);
                    et.setText("0");
                } else {
                    listDrinkQuantity.get(position).quantity = num;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    };
}

private View.OnClickListener onClick(@NonNull AddDrinkViewHolder holder, int position, String mode) {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int qty = listDrinkQuantity.get(position).quantity;
            if (mode.equals("minus")) {
                if(qty == 0) {
                    listener.onChangeText(min,max,-1);
                    return; // min 0 : abort
                }
                qty--;
                holder.mEtQuantity.setText(Integer.toString(qty));
            } else if (mode.equals("add")) {
                if(qty == 5) {
                    listener.onChangeText(min,max,6);
                    return; // max 5 : abort
                }
                qty++;
                holder.mEtQuantity.setText(Integer.toString(qty));
            }
        }
    };
}
}
```

`DrinkDetailAdapter` Class

```
public class DrinkDetailAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DrinkDataViewHolder> {
private static final String TAG = DrinkDetailAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
private ArrayList<Drink> drinkList = new ArrayList<>();
private final String NAME = "name";
private final String SUGAR = "sugar";
private final String ICE = "ice";

DrinkDetailAdapter(ArrayList<Drink> drink_list) {
    drinkList = drink_list;
}

ArrayList<Drink> getDrinkDetailsArrayList() {
    return drinkList;
}

void reset() {
    for(int i=0; i < drinkList.size(); i++) {
        drinkList.get(i).getDrinkDetails().drink_name = "";
        drinkList.get(i).getDrinkDetails().sugar = "0";
        drinkList.get(i).getDrinkDetails().ice = "0";
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public DrinkDataViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_drink_check, parent, false);

    return new DrinkDataViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DrinkDataViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Drink drink = drinkList.get(position);
    holder.mEtName.setText(drink.getDrinkDetails().drink_name);
    holder.mEtSugar.setText(drink.getDrinkDetails().sugar);
    holder.mEtIce.setText(drink.getDrinkDetails().ice);

    holder.mEtName.addTextChangedListener(updateData(position, NAME, holder));
    holder.mEtSugar.addTextChangedListener(updateData(position, SUGAR, holder));
    holder.mEtIce.addTextChangedListener(updateData(position, ICE, holder));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return drinkList.size();
}

TextWatcher updateData(int position, String editText, @NonNull DrinkDataViewHolder holder) {
    return new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            switch (editText) {
                case NAME:
                    drinkList.get(position).getDrinkDetails().drink_name = charSequence.toString();
                    break;
                case SUGAR:
                    drinkList.get(position).getDrinkDetails().sugar = charSequence.toString();
                    break;
                case ICE:
                    drinkList.get(position).getDrinkDetails().ice = charSequence.toString();
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    };
}
}
```

After getting `Drink` quantities, this is the code to update the `DrinkDetailAdapter` `ArrayList`

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_ADD_DRINK) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                Bundle args = data.getBundleExtra("args");
                if (args != null) {
                    drinkCheckResponse = args.getParcelable(DRINK_CHECK_RESPONSE);
                    drinkQuantityList.clear();
                    drinkQuantityList.addAll(drinkCheckResponse.getData().drink_quantities);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Logger.e(TAG, "onActivityResult Exception: msg[%s]", e.getMessage());
                Logger.logException(e);
            }
            updateDrinkList();
        }
    }
}

private void updateDrinkList() {
    for(int i = 0; i < drinkQuantityList.size(); i++) {
        setDrinkList(drinkQuantityList.get(i).drink_type, drinkQuantityList.get(i).quantity);
    }
    drinkDetailsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void setDrinkList(String name, int enteredQuantity) {
    int drinkTypeCount = drinkTypeCount(name);
    int diffCount = enteredQuantity-drinkTypeCount;
    if (diffCount != 0) {
        addRemoveDrink(diffCount, enteredQuantity, name);
    }
}

private int drinkTypeCount(String name) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < drinkList.size(); i++) {
        String subName = drinkList.get(i).getDrinkDetails().drink_name.substring(0, drinkList.get(i).getDrinkDetails().drink_name.indexOf("(")).trim();
        if(subName.equals(name)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

private void addRemoveDrink(int diffCount, int enteredQuantity, String name) {
    if(diffCount > 0) {
        for(int i=enteredQuantity-diffCount+1; i <= enteredQuantity; i++) {
            DrinkDetails drinkDetails = new DrinkDetails(name + " (" + i + ")");
            drinkList.add(new Drink(drinkDetails));
        }
    } else if(diffCount < 0) {
        for(int i=enteredQuantity-diffCount; i > enteredQuantity; i--) {
            for (Iterator<Drink> iterator = drinkList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                Drink drink = iterator.next();
                if (drink.getDrinkDetails().drink_name.equals(name + " (" + i + ")")) {
                    // Remove the current element from the iterator and the list.
                    iterator.remove();
                    drinkDetailsAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(drinkList.indexOf(drink));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(drinkList);
    Log.d(TAG, "addRemoveDrink: " + drinkList.size());
}
```

This is the error that I received when I add 10-15 quantity(total for all drink type), then minus the quantity to 0 or 1 for each type.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: my.com.time.tapins, PID: 4143
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 13, Size: 3
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
    at my.com.time.tapins.ui.drinkcheck.DrinkDetailAdapter$3.onTextChanged(DrinkDetailAdapter.java:121)
    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:10535)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6272)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6097)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6049)
    at my.com.time.tapins.ui.drinkcheck.DrinkDetailAdapter.onBindViewHolder(DrinkDetailAdapter.java:67)
    at my.com.time.tapins.ui.drinkcheck.DrinkDetailAdapter.onBindViewHolder(DrinkDetailAdapter.java:21)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5752)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6019)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3336)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
    at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(NestedScrollView.java:1502)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.onMeasure(NestedScrollView.java:556)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:742)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3006)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1833)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2122)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1721)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7598)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:790)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:725)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:951)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 13, Size: 3
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
    at my.com.time.tapins.ui.drinkcheck.DrinkDetailAdapter$3.onTextChanged(DrinkDetailAdapter.java:121)
    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:10535)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6272)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6097)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6049)
    at my.com.time.tapins.ui.drinkcheck.DrinkDetailAdapter.onBindViewHolder(DrinkDetailAdapter.java:67)
    at my.com.time.tapins.ui.drinkcheck.DrinkDetailAdapter.onBindViewHolder(DrinkDetailAdapter.java:21)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5752)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6019)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3336)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
    at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(NestedScrollView.java:1502)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.onMeasure(NestedScrollView.java:556)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:742)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3006)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1833)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2122)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1721)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7598)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:790)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:725)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:951)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Basically this is the 2 pages for this two `RecyclerView` Adapter.

Screenshot of adding/removing drink quantities
[image]

Screenshot of showing the drink detail
[image]

`Drink` Class

```
public class Drink implements Comparable<Drink>, Parcelable {
private DrinkDetails drink_details;

public Drink() {
}

public Drink(DrinkDetails drink_details) {
    this.drink_details = drink_details;
}

protected Drink(Parcel in) {
}

public static final Creator<Drink> CREATOR = new Creator<Drink>() {
    @Override
    public Drink createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Drink(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Drink[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Drink[size];
    }
};

public DrinkDetails getDrinkDetails() {
    return drink_details;
}

private String getDrinkName() {
    return getDrinkDetails().drink_name;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Drink drink) {
    if(drink.drink_details.drink_name.compareToIgnoreCase(getDrinkName()) > 0){
        return -1;
    } else if(drink.drink_details.drink_name.compareToIgnoreCase(getDrinkName()) < 0){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
}
}
```

`DrinkQuantity` Class

```
public class DrinkQuantity implements Parcelable {
public String drink_type;
public int quantity;

public DrinkQuantity() {
}

public DrinkQuantity(String drink_type, int quantity) {
    this.drink_type = drink_type;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

protected DrinkQuantity(Parcel in) {
    drink_type = in.readString();
    quantity = in.readInt();
}

public static final Creator<DrinkQuantity> CREATOR = new Creator<DrinkQuantity>() {
    @Override
    public DrinkQuantity createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new DrinkQuantity(in);
    }

    @Override
    public DrinkQuantity[] newArray(int size) {
        return new DrinkQuantity[size];
    }
};

public String getDrinkType() {
    return drink_type;
}

public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(drink_type);
    parcel.writeInt(quantity);
}
}
```

I find the structure very confusing as the `AddDrinkAdapter` uses `ArrayList<DrinkQuantity>` and `DrinkDetailAdapter` uses `ArrayList<Drink>` then I need to perform loop to match those 2 lists. If anyone could change the structure to make this better, please do tell me. Thanks.

Comment: I think you are deleting of an item from the main list that is related to items in detail list for deleting , first delete related items in detail list. If you delete first from the main list , you must notify and if it is not possible please reinitialize two adapters with the two lists.

Comment: Thanks @maniaq for the suggestion. Will look into it later, got to attend another issue this week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging for hours on this issue, finally I saw what was the problem.
My updateData function was the one causing me problem as it is holding the original `int position`.

So, this is my updated code to solve this issue.

`DrinkDetailAdapter` Class

```
TextWatcher updateData(String editText, @NonNull DrinkDataViewHolder holder) {
    return new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            Drink drink = getDrink(holder.mTvDrinkName.getText().toString());
            if(drink == null) return;
            switch (editText) {
                switch (editText) {
                    case NAME:
                        drinkList.get(drinkList.indexOf(drink)).getDrinkDetails().drink_name = charSequence.toString();
                        break;
                    case SUGAR:
                        drinkList.get(drinkList.indexOf(drink)).getDrinkDetails().sugar = charSequence.toString();
                        break;
                    case ICE:
                        drinkList.get(drinkList.indexOf(drink)).getDrinkDetails().ice = charSequence.toString();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    };
}

private Drink getDrink(String name) {
    for (Drink drink : drinkList) {
        if (drink.getDrinkDetails().drink_name.equalsIgnoreCase(name))
            return drink;
    }
    return null;
}
```